# Java Bit Manipulation - What does (num >>= 1) do?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I was looking at some code that outputs a number to the binary form with prepended 0s.

```
    byte number = 48;
    int i = 256; //max number * 2
    while( (i >>= 1) > 0) {
        System.out.print(((number & i) != 0 ? "1" : "0"));
    }
```

and didn't understand what the `i >>= 1` does. I know that `i >> 1` shifts to the right by 1 bit but didn't understand what the `=` does and as far as I know, it is not possible to do a search for ">>=" to find out what it means.

Comment: A slight improvement would be `while((i >>>= 1) != 0)` as the current loop would not do anything if you gave it `i = 1 << 31` and you could never printout the top bit of a 32-bit number.

Answer (score 22):

`i >>= 1` is just shorhand for `i = i >> 1` in the same way that `i += 4` is short for `i = i + 4`

EDIT: Specifically, those are both examples of [compound assignment operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#5304).

Comment: And, specifically, it's a sign-extending shift.

Comment: Mathematically right shifting a number by 1 is equivalent to the dividing the number by 2.